# Getting error while changing rules in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

Im getting error while changing rules in `firebase` someone please help in debugging it and let me know how should i do it

Error message:

> **Error saving rules - Line 1: mismatched input '{' expecting {'function', 'import', 'service', 'rules_version'}**

```
{
  "rules": {
   ".read": "auth === null",
   ".write": "auth === null"
   }
}
```

Comment: is it realtime database or firestore? rules are different

Comment: In firebase i'm trying to change authentication rules

Comment: Firebase has two databases: the Realtime Database, and Cloud Firestore. And while they're both part of Firebase, they're complete separate and have their own security rules languages. It looks like you're trying to set rules for the Firebase Realtime Database into Cloud Firestore. You'll need to set the rules of the database your code is actually using.